# Unable to install python on Azure batch pool -- Invalid argument get returned

Tags: azure, azure-batch

In my implementation of Azure batch, I am trying to install Python3.7.3 as part of the pool starttask event. However, I am not succeeding with this. Start task fails almost in all the times, returning 'invalid arguments'. What am I missing? Please help.

pool.ApplicationPackageReferences = new List
    {
        new ApplicationPackageReference
        {
            ApplicationId = "PythonInstall",
            Version = "1.0"
        }
    };

```
string appPath = String.Format("%AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_{0}#{1}%", appPackage_pyInstall_ID, appPackage_pyInstall_Version);

pool.StartTask = new StartTask()
{
    CommandLine = $@" CMD.exe / copy --% {appPath}\python-3.7.3-amd64.exe  %AZ_BATCH_NODE_STARTUP_DIR% && %AZ_BATCH_NODE_STARTUP_DIR%\python-3.7.3-amd64.exe /quiet InstallAllUsers=0 PrependPath=1 Include_test=0 TargetDir = %AZ_BATCH_NODE_STARTUP_DIR%",
    UserIdentity = new UserIdentity(new AutoUserSpecification(elevationLevel: ElevationLevel.Admin, scope: AutoUserScope.Task)),
    WaitForSuccess = true,
};
```

Ideally, I expect the installation to complete quietly but it is not happening :(

Answer (score 1):

Please see https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-batch-samples/blob/328be5fe51e99297c69686cf30d1d2a06439af75/Python/Batch/sample4_job_scheduler.py#L49 for a working sample of an install python command.

I believe the core problem in your command is you did not include /c in your cmd.exe execution.

```
CMD.exe /
```

Should actually be:

```
CMD.exe /c
```

Comment: Thank you Brklein. No I have /c in my working code. It is missing because of a typo when I was writing the code here in Stackoverflow. So, the missing /c is not the issue in my case as it is there. Something must be lurking out there.

Comment: I am still not having any luck with this. Any one who could help me unstuck please?

Comment: Have you tried executing your python install with the /passive option instead? If there were mistakes formatting you code sample you should correct them otherwise it doesn't provide much value.  The sample provided has a command-line for installing python that works, so you will need to collect client side logs to see what exactly in your command is failing.

Comment: @DWorkie Did this help or are you still stuck? If either this helped or you found your own answer could you accept an answer?